# OpenGL Pyglet "Error: global name 'texture' not defined"

Tags: opengl, textures, pyglet

The error is on line 5: glBindTexture(texture.target, texture.id)

```
1. import pyglet
2. from pyglet.gl import *
3. class CustomGroup(pyglet.graphics.Group):
4.    def set_state(self):
5.        glEnable(texture.target)
6.        glBindTexture(texture.target, texture.id)
7.    def unset_state(self):
8.        glDisable(texture.target)
```

NameError: global name 'texture' not defined
but i imported it on line 2.
the full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/10JbiCYp)

Any help? 
I am using python 2.7.3 with pyglet and ubuntu 12.04

Comment: -1, pastebins die, SO is forever.  Edit the code into the question.

Comment: i always set my pastebins to never expire, but thanks for the tip. however, sometimes you want to link to the full code, and only show the portion that is relavent @genpfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pyglet.gl` module does not define any variable `texture`, so your import statement in line 2 does not provide anything like that. And what do you even expect it to contain? You'll need to create your [`Texture`](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.image.Texture-class.html) object yourself.

To do so, you could use the methods [`pyglet.resource.image`](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.resource-module.html#image) or [`pyglet.resource.texture`](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.resource-module.html#texture) or you could load an `AbstractImage` by calling [`pyglet.image.load`](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.image-module.html#load) and retrieve a corresponding `Texture` object by accessing the image's `texture` member or, say, adding it to a [`TextureAtlas`](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/image_sequences_and_atlases.html#texture-bins-and-atlases).

Why don't you add to your code:

```
img = pyglet.image.load('imagefile.png')
texture = img.texture
```

and don't forget to alter your `vertex_list` [accordingly](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/vertex_attributes.html) to make use of the texture.

Comment: thanks, that's the problem. i forget to change the path to the correct texture file